# Laravel redirect and continue executing script

Tags: php, redirect, laravel

How can I redirect user and then store data in database about that user.

```
return Redirect::to('http:www.google.com');
// Strore analytics
$ip = $_SERVER['...']
$analytic = new Analytic();
$analytic->ip = $ip;
$analytic->save();
```

Actually there is not only ip. I need to store a lot more data and if I first store that and then return redirect user needs to wait until everything is finished.

How to first redirect and then continue savin data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't do that. Once you redirect the user to a different location then the code after that line won't be executed. You should save the data first and then redirect and it shouldn't take much time (IMO).

### But...

If you want to redirect the user first (without saving the data) then you may use Laravel's `queue`. You may create a class like this:

```
class SaveData {
    public function fire($job, $data)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Then you may use the class like this:

```
Queue::push('SaveData', array('ip' => $ip, 'otherField' => 'value'));
return Redirect::to('someurl');
```

There are several drivers available and you need to setup configuration in `app/config/queue.php`, so read more about [queues](http://laravel.com/docs/queues). This is just a basic idea about `queue`, read more on the Laravel website.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Sentry to Handle User sessions??

https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry

http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/sentry

eg,

```
$user = Sentry::getUser();

    if ( isset($user) )
    {
      $id = Helpers::loggedInUser()->id;
     $ip = Helpers::loggedInUser()->ip;

     }
```